# Transformation from Sphere_Natural_Earth to WGS1984

Tags: coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics, projection-mathematics

I have a set of files that are stored in Tom Patterson's [Natural Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Earth_projection) Projection, and I would like to convert them to WGS1984. This will require a transformation, but I can't locate one and don't know where to start with building one, if that's the route this needs to go.

I seek help with methods for reprojecting.

To avoid any confusion, this is NOT the same projection that the Natural Earth data comes in (see the link for disambiguation).

So that you can see the Datum etc., the .prj string is:

PROJCS["Sphere_Natural_Earth",GEOGCS["GCS_Sphere_GRS_1980_Mean_Radius",DATUM["D_Sphere_GRS_1980_Mean_Radius",SPHEROID["Sphere_GRS_1980_Mean_Radius",6371008.7714,0.0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Natural_Earth"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",90.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",90.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",180.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! My colleague, Bojan, has posted an answer on [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/229362-reproject-patterson-natural-earth-to-wgs84-or-anything-really).